# Django load custom template filter outside of app

Tags: django

Is it possible to load custom template filters which resides outside of an app?

eg.

```
|-Apps
|  |----home
|
|-Contrib
   |----templatetags
          |-----------custom_filters.py
```

When I load the filters in a template:

```
{% load custom_filters %}
```

I get:

```
'custom_filters' is not a valid tag library: Template library custom_filters not found,
```

Comment: According to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout): `The app that contains the custom tags must be in INSTALLED_APPS in order for the {% load %} tag to work.` Do you have `Contrib` in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Answer (score 0):

You `Contrib` directory must be containts `__init__.py` file